# Does WCF offer options to avoid port forwarding?

Tags: c#, wcf, nat, portforwarding

So many programs in the past and even the present operate on a Server/Client basis. Examples include TeamSpeak, Ventrilo, Mumble, etc. These programs typically require going into the router and forwarding ports so that the computer running the server can get the messages from the clients which are sending connection requests to the server's router.

Is there anything in WCF these days that allow you to prevent that sort of thing? I have a chat/file transfer program and I would really prefer that users not have to know how to forward their ports.

What kind of options are there out there in the way of UPnP or Punchthrough? The notion of having to go through and forward all the specific ports that a program uses seems so outdated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at WS-Discovery with WCF:

http://weblogs.asp.net/gsusx/archive/2009/02/13/using-ws-discovery-in-wcf-4-0.aspx

The discovery protocol negates a central, "server router" as you put it. It's uses UDP broadcast to notify clients of each other.

Note that the discovery protocol itself is just a stateless messaging protocol. It has no guarantees or state synchronization. If for example, Client A doesn't receive the broadcast message from Client B, then Client A wont know of Client B. The protocol overhead of maintaining this P2P states is complex and usually a single server to hold this state is the easiest approach.

Comment: Well right now my program has a server and client rolled into one, where the user can select to be a server or a client. You say it notifies clients of each other. Is there any way to do this so that the server and client can be automatically configured with the router?

Comment: Unfortunately after experimenting with WCF Discovery, it doesn't seem to offer what I'm looking for. I guess nothing does. There's no built in mechanism to create a tunnel between a server and a client without that server having to forward their ports. I was hoping that with discovery, when the service broadcast, and later a client looked for that service, it would wire the two connections together and totally avoiding the need for network address translations. I guess I was wrong though.